# SSRS Count and Expression function

Tags: reporting-services, count

I am trying to count the number of packages which belong to the Area by using the count. Every Area has different number of Packages.

How can I use Count here and check how many packages for a specific Area.
Also there is a attribute called 'Delivered' with defined values as D,N,P.
I want to check and calculate how much percentage of packages are in state 'D'.

Can anyone help.
I tried using the count but no luck.
=Count(Fields!Delivered.Value = 'D')

Answer (score 0):

To get a count of specific records you can use something like this.

```
= SUM(Fields!Area.Value = "abc", 1, 0)
```

To get a percentage of the Delivered field do something like

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Delivered.Value = 1, 1, 0), "DataSet1")
 / Count(Fields!Delivered.Value , "DataSet1")
```

Make sure you change DataSet1 to match the dataset that the Delivered field comes form (you must include the quotes)

Comment: Hi Alan, Thanks fro your reply. I think I was not able to explain what I exactly needed.When I am making a SSRS report I made a group for country as shown in the fig below and packages to be delivered to a specific area in that country and status of delivery. But I also needed % status of parcels delivered and not delivered. Which I was trying using the count and then using another expression.

Comment: Country City           Status % Parcels Delivered % Parcels not Delivered
India Delhi Delivered   
         Pune  Inprocess  
        Noida Not Dispatched  
        Cochi Delivered   
UK London  Delivered   
 Manchester Inprocess  
 Bristol Not Dispatched  
 Belfast Inprocess  
 Liverpool Not Dispatched  
Hi Alan, Thanks for your reply. I think I was not able to explain what exactly I wanted to do with this. I have added a table above as I needed in SSRS. where I created a group as per country. Here I need to extract a % for packages delivered and % packages not delivered.